# Finite State Machine: One State to Multiple States

Tags: state-machine

I'm writing a simple finite state machine and realized that there are situations where an event can take a state to more than one possible results. Basically, from state A, if Event E happens, the state could be either C or D.

I'm currently using the Javascript Finite State Machine code written here: https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine

From the documentation I don't see an obvious way that makes this possible. More so, I feel like maybe this is actually a flow in my original design.

Essentially, in a Finite State Machine, should there be a situation where a transition happens, and based on some logic result in one of multiple states (1 to many), or should it be that we check the logic to see which transition needs to takes place (1 to 1)?

Comment: flow or flaw? Actually, I don't understand your question. In finite state machines (DFA, NFA), there could obviously be many transitions from a state, based on the input symbol.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Basically I was under the assumption that all state-machines are deterministic, i.e., given a state and an event, only one possible state can be the result. In my original design there was a situation where given a state and an event, one of 2 possible states could be the result. This basically wasn't possible using the library I was using since it was written for a DFA.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations, you've just discovered [non-deterministic finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton)!  The ideas are similar to that of a deterministic state machine, except that there may be multiple ways to transition from a state given the same input symbol.  How this is actually done is unspecified (randomness, user input, branch out and run them all at once, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! That was my basic question. Do you know any good popular JS libraries for NFA?

Comment: @beichenfan No, I do not.  However, because the specifics of an NFA are by definition undefined, there's no way to make a general-purpose NFA library.   So you have to decide what you really want; for example, if you want randomness, I'm sure there's a decent Markov chain library somewhere.